# Sharing single page application for multiple customers

Tags: security, web, architecture

I'm looking for information to implement the following architecture:

- One Single Page Application hosted on AWS S3 + Cloudfront distribution - domain **example.com**
- A single API accessed by the single page application - domain **api.example.com**
- Every company has a dedicated DNS subdomain pointing to the Cloudfront distribution. For example, company A has dedicated subdomain **companyA.example.com** (implemented using a CNAME record)
- When a customer of company A accesses the domain **companyA.example.com**, its browser communicates with the API which MUST know that the customer came from this subdomain, therefore associating the customer to company A (remember, there is only one API)
- Of course, all communications are HTTPS

The following points are critical:

- The API MUST have a reliable way to know the subdomain "from" which the request has been sent - is the `Origin` header reliable?
- Customers of company A cannot be forced to access subdomain of another company (customers stealing) - I guess this is more of a question of DNS protection

After exposing all this information, I think I can resume my question as:

**How can the API know "for sure" the subdomain a customer came "from" ?**

Comment: It is not really clear what your question is. One thing though: We don't design solutions. Instead, if you have trouble implementing the one you designed, ask a specific question about that problem.

Comment: I introduced with information that helps understand the question that I asked at the end of the post.